# Rails validate polymorphic associated model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my Rails 5.2 app, I have a polymorphic model Vehicle of types Car, Bike, Jeep etc. which has belongs_to association vehicle_type. I would like to validate associated record attribute display_name. The following code snippet does the job but I would like to know a better way to do this.

```
class Car < Vehicle
      validates :vehicle_type,
        :inclusion => {
          :in => [VehicleType.find_by(display_name: 'four wheeler')],
          :message => "A Car can only be of vehicle_type 'four wheeler'",
        }
    }
```

Comment: it seem like this could have been an enum.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the validation on the id rather than the display name since you would have to refactor your code if you ever decide to change the display name.

```
class VehiculeType
  FOUR_WHEELER = 1 (id of the four_wheeler type)
end

class Car < Vehicule
  validate :validate_vehicule_type

  private

  def validate_vehicule_type
   errors.add(:vehicule, "A Car can only be of vehicle_type 'four wheeler'") unless vehicule_type_id == VehiculeType::FOUR_WHEELER
  end

end
```

Comment: I don't think this a good idea, his vehicle_type is an entity, so you have to looking for in the database.

Comment: wait I must have misread his question. Usually polymorphic model_type are class names and not models. Changed my answer accordingly, thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the best way, but I'll share what i have done in one of my projects:

I decided to extend `ActiveModel::Validator` and create my own validation for my polymorphic associations

In you case

```
class CarValidator < ActiveModel::Validator 
  def validate_vehicle_type(record)
     # where did you save the veicle type associatuon?
     unless VehicleType.find_by(display_name:  record.veicle_type).exists?
    record.errors.add :veicle_type, "This veicle type does not exist"
  end 
end
```

then `validates with CarValidator`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mathieu Larouche. One small thing I would add to this discussion is that this is not really a polymorphic association, as polymorphic associations are about how "a model can belong to more than one other model, on a single association". This is done via a combination of `type` and `id` fields (`imageable_id` and `imageable_type`, for example). See docs [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

It doesn't really affect the response your question, but I just wanted to mention it because polymorphic associations took me forever to wrap my head around, and I thought calling out the distinction could be helpful.